# Comma or No Comma? Workplace and Title

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, punctuation, writing-style

> Anthony Martin, assistant accountant, PwC, and associate editor, Washington Post.

The commas above look a little too much.

Are they technically all correct?

Which would you recommend removed? I was thinking of removing the one before "and" since it looks the most clunky, but feel that comma is necessary here.

Comment: You could consider using **and** before PwC and Washington Post. You don't need a comma before **and**.

Comment: This is a matter of style, and thus there are almost guaranteed to be conflicting opinions – correctness is a vague concept hereabouts and 'technically correct' a misnomer. Here's one suggestion: << Anthony Martin – assistant accountant, PwC, and associate editor – Washington Post.>>  Here's another: << Anthony Martin; assistant accountant, PwC, and associate editor; Washington Post.>> These avoid the spot-the-comma-role hurdle, but still look inelegant.

Comment: Why not though, Rathony? I feel the comma is a bracketing comma. Similar to the comma in: He lives in Washington, United States, and loves it there.

Comment: Thanks Edwin, that does look better but my issue is that I have to type out two pages of this -- name of the event followed by speakers. I thought any dashes would stick out too much, semicolons have been taken up for separating multiple speakers for the same event, and so that leaves only the comma. I've given up on trying to make it look elegant and so posting here since I don't feel like giving up on it being grammatically correct as well.

Comment: @ChristineChua The more commas you use, the worse your writing will be. It is primarily-opinion-based advice. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would write it like this: **"Mr. Anthony Martins, Assistant Accountant, PwC; and Associate Editor, *The Washington Post,*"** since his accountancy with PricewaterhouseCoopers, LLC, is functionally discrete from his editorship with the Washington Post newspaper (even though they are likely related). In this instance, he has two different employers.

Comment: Thanks, Hubbard. That does look better and I did consider formatting it like so except that it's a list of three people whom I divided using semicolons. Wanted to leave semicolons for that use exclusively. As an aside, the other question I posted is about capitalizing work titles and I can't help but notice that you capitalized them where I chose to leave them un-capitalized.

Comment: Ms. Chua, Then a comma would suffice after PwC, but the titles of the positions he holds should definitely be capitalized, as they also would be on his letterhead and business cards.

Comment: Hubbard, I'm glad I'm not the only one who thinks like that about capitalization. To me un-capitalized looks odd but my search on Google has revealed that the trend is toward less capitalization. Most of the advice I found when searching recommended not capitalizing unless the title comes before the name.

Comment: I refer to my wife as a retired accountant (lower case), which might *account* for the trend, but her title was Senior Staff Accountant at the firm where she worked. A formal title should always be capitalized.

Comment: @Rathony, I think I was more citing my confusion and the reason for my other question here which is on capitalizing titles. The title of president is an exception, but I think you could find advice to not capitalize secretary of state or secretary general if you search for it. So I guess it's a matter of style now, except in sentences like "the work of being a president took up his later years ..." or "he works as an accountant at ..." where capitalization would be inappropriate